# Function where I can write a description next to the map in R

Tags: r

I want to create a map in R with the description left of the box or just below the box of the map

```
tm_shape(Europe) +
    tm_fill("pop_est_dens", style="kmeans", textNA="Non-European countries", 
    title="Country population density (per km2)") +
    tm_borders() +
tm_shape(rivers) +
    tm_lines("dodgerblue3") +
tm_shape(metro) +
    tm_text("name", size="pop2010", scale=1, ymod=-.02, root=4, size.lowerbound = .60, 
        bg.color="yellow", bg.alpha = .5) + 
    tm_bubbles("pop2010", "red", border.col = "black", border.lwd=1, size.lim = c(0, 11e6), 
        sizes.legend = seq(2e6,10e6, by=2e6), title.size="Metropolitan Population") +
tm_shape(Europe) +
    tm_text("iso_a3", size="area", scale=1.5, root=8, size.lowerbound = .40, 
        fontface="bold", case=NA, fontcolor = "gray35") + 
tm_layout_Europe("Map of Europe")
```

My output looks like these:
[image]

Now how can I add a short description next or below or top of the box of the map?

edit:

```
library(tmap)
library(sf)
example(st_read)
tm_shape(nc) + tm_fill("NWBIR74")
```

Comment: Note that the Europe dataset and the Europe layout have been removed from recent tmap packages. This code won't work with the latest CRAN tmap.

Comment: I edited for nc

Comment: If you resize your graphics device then `tmap` keeps the box aspect ratio, leaving space under and above the box which you can draw on using `text`. EG your map on an A4 portrait PDF would have masses of space. This is a bit of a hack since it depends on knowing your graphics device and having some control over that. Where is this map ultimately going? Another option could be having a caption in knitr/markdown...

Comment: okay thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to put text on the spare space outside a box in a graphics device:

First you need to call `plot.new` to set up the coordinate system to come later:

```
plot.new()
```

Then make your map:

```
tm_shape(nc) + tm_fill("NWBIR74")
```

Now set clipping off so things outside the box show up:

```
par(xpd=TRUE)
```

And we'll put some text here:

```
x = 0.5 ; y = 0.2
text(x, y, "This is thinking outside the box")
```

Giving:

[image]

Note this is dependent on the shape of the graphics device. If I resize my window then the text is not outside the box any more.

[image]

It might be better to look at the underlying grid graphics system for layout of tmap objects:

```
tt = tm_shape(nc) + tm_fill("NWBIR74")
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
grid.draw(arrangeGrob(tmap_grob(tt), bottom="This is\na caption"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide available data, I made an example based on another file. I followed the answers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60892033/how-do-you-position-the-title-and-legend-in-tmap and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55977722/how-do-i-add-an-additional-comment-to-a-map-using-tmap-in-r. I hope I understood your problem correctly.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(tmap)

bbox_new <- st_bbox(border)

xrange <- bbox_new$xmax - bbox_new$xmin
yrange <- bbox_new$ymax - bbox_new$ymin

bbox_new[2] <- bbox_new[2] - (0.15 * yrange)
bbox_new[4] <- bbox_new[4] + (0.15 * yrange)

bbox_new <- bbox_new %>% 
  st_as_sfc()

tm_shape(border, bbox = bbox_new) +
  tm_borders() +
  tm_layout(title = "Title above map", frame = T)+
  tm_credits("Text under the map", position = c("RIGHT", "BOTTOM"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

You need to specify how much you enlarge your object's bbox depending on the size of the text you place (I enlarged it by 15%).

I corrected the example. I used the data available in the spData package (you can see how simplified the border is in this data). I also removed the frame.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(tmap)
library(spData)
library(tidyverse)

border <- world %>% 
  filter(name_long == "Poland") %>% 
  select(-everything())

bbox_new <- st_bbox(border)

xrange <- bbox_new$xmax - bbox_new$xmin
yrange <- bbox_new$ymax - bbox_new$ymin


bbox_new[2] <- bbox_new[2] - (0.15 * yrange)
bbox_new[4] <- bbox_new[4] + (0.15 * yrange)

bbox_new <- bbox_new %>% 
  st_as_sfc()

tm_shape(border, bbox = bbox_new) +
  tm_borders() +
  tm_layout(title = "Title above the map", frame = FALSE)+
  tm_credits("Text under the map", position = c("RIGHT", "BOTTOM"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: yes, thanks, but is it possible to write under the box?

Comment: Now, it is within the box

Comment: What's "border" here? This isn't a reproducible example without it, despite the tag.

Comment: @Spacedman I corrected the example.

Comment: @PM4s I have no idea how to make the inscription below the frame, but it can be turned off as in the corrected example.

Comment: no problem, what you present is useful too